# Difference on hibernate session state between HibernateTemplate findByCriteria and Get

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

I have the following strange behaviour.

I have some testcases which before starting creates TestValues.
First the main entity is created and saved with a Test Value ID.
For this I use saveOrUpdate from Springs HibernateTemplate.

Then some children objects are created and attached to this object in 
a children collection. (which has cascade="save-update" in the hbm.xml)
These children objects do not have an ID assigned at that point.

Then an additional saveOrUpdate is called.

On every saveOrUpdate on my entity an additional Audit Entry is saved
in the database. For this each time a DetachedCriteria is created which
searches for the current user by username and references it in the Audit entry.
Til that point everything works fine. Every children objects gets an ID assigned.

After some profiling I found out that this DetachedCriteria takes a lot of time 
and decided to change it so that I can access the User by the get method from HibernateTemplate by id which is much more efficient.

But know something weird happens. The saveOrUpdate on the entity with the children doesnt result in ID Generation for the children and as it looks it doesnt save the children at all.

As I read here http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-save-vs-saveorupdate-vs-persist-vs-merge-vs-update-explanation-with-examples the HibernateTemplate saveOrUpdate is different to persist so that it can be used outside any transaction which would lead to the above behaviour that mapped collections wont be saved until it gets flushed. 
So what I dont understand is why is there a different behaviour when I use a findByCriteria with a detachedCriteria in the HibernateTemplate.

Does calling findByCriteria invoke a flush on the session, or why is there a different state of the hibernate session, when calling get instead of findByCriteria.
There is no direct reference between the auditentry, the user account and the entity which is saved during test values creation.

PS: I do know that HibernateTemplate use is not recommended nowadays. But its an old application and it would take too much time to replace it completly.

Answer (score 0):

so I think I found what the problem was.
The old code with the TestValues which used SaveOrUpdate and generated immediatly IDs for the children collection was only working by chance.

During the findByCriteria the method list is called which goes to SessionImpl of Hibernate where inside autoFlushIfRequired a flush is called. During that method the session is flushed and the detached children get their ID.

When I changed findByCriteria to the get method of HibernateTemplate this list() method is not called thus no flush is invoked.

So I did a manual flush on the session after saveOrUpdate and the IDs get generated at that moment.